# How to insert '01' to varchar2 column using bind variables in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a table `BIND_TEST` with one column `COL_1 varchar2(2 bytes)`.

I want to insert 2 rows of data: `01` and `10` to the table using bind variables.

First the select statements:

```
select :val_1 as COL_1 from dual;

Bind Variable value: 01

COL_1
--------
01

Bind Variable value: 10

COL_1
--------
10
```

Everything is OK till now. Now the insert statement:

```
insert into BIND_TEST
select :val_1 as COL_1 from dual;

Bind Variable value: 01

COL_1
--------
1

Bind Variable value: 10

COL_1
--------
10
```

For values starting from `0`, The value is not inserting properly.
How should we handle this when using BIND VARIABLES?

Comment: This sounds like a casting issue, i.e. the number `1` is being treated as numeric, therefore the leading zero is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use TO_CHAR function to insert value as a string.

```
INSERT INTO bind_test
SELECT TO_CHAR(:val_1, '00') AS col_1
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this (air code):

```
INSERT INTO bind_test
SELECT LPAD(:val_1, 2, '0') AS col_1
FROM dual;
```

And, for reference: [LPAD documention](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm)